# How do I iterate a .Net IList collection in the reverse order?

Tags: .net, collections, iteration

I have an IList that contains items ( parent first ), they need to be added to a Diagram Document in the reverse order so that the parent is added last, drawn on top so that it is the first thing to be selected by the user.

What's the best way to do it? Something better/more elegant than what I am doing currently
which I post below..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have .NET 3.5 you could use LINQ's Reverse?

```
foreach(var item in obEvtArgs.NewItems.Reverse())
{
   ...
}
```

(Assuming you're talking about the generic IList)

Comment: I was about to give up because I couldn't find the System.Linq namespace in intellisense. I'm working with NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs which uses a System.Collections.IList.. so I can't Reverse() anyways..thx. voted up.

Comment: you could always use a (new List<Object>(obEvtArgs.NewItems)).Reverse(), but you'll get higher memory usage and lesser performance.

Comment: :) For loops are more familiar and readable to me atleast. Need to get acquainted with LINQ one of these days...

Comment: will this use reversed indexing or cause copy?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments to [Davy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90996?sort=votes#91044), and [Gishu's original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90996?sort=votes#90998), you could cast your weakly-typed `System.Collections.IList` to a generic collection using the `System.Linq.Enumerable.Cast` extension method:

```
var reversedCollection = obEvtArgs.NewItems
  .Cast<IMySpecificObject>( )
  .Reverse( );
```

This removes the noise of both the reverse `for` loop, and the `as` cast to get a strongly-typed object from the original collection.

Answer (score 0):

NewItems is my List here... This is a bit clunky though.

```
for(int iLooper = obEvtArgs.NewItems.Count-1; iLooper >= 0; iLooper--)
            {
                GoViewBoy.Document.Add(CreateNodeFor(obEvtArgs.NewItems[iLooper] as IMySpecificObject, obNextPos));
            }
```

Comment: why not include this in the question?  Why post as an answer?

Comment: From the FAQ: 
Can I answer my own question? What if it's not really a question?
It's best to actually submit an answer, rather than just answering in the question itself. This allows the answer to be voted on and evaluated fairly against other people's answers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need LINQ:

```csharp
var reversed = new List<T>(original); // assuming original has type IList<T>
reversed.Reverse();
foreach (T e in reversed) {
  ...
}
```